# Matching the borders of a split text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

So I'm trying to match the borders of this split text. I think I can do it by moving all the anchor points but that would be tedious.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make the text with a stroke color and copy it

[image]

- Make a rectangle covering the lower half of the text

[image]

- Select the rectangle and the text and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> Win to create a Clipping Mask

[image]

- Use the Direct Selection Tool to select this masked text and fill it with a color

[image]

- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Win to paste the original text in place and send it back

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The great thing about this method is it leaves the text **live** so it can be edited easily when needed.

[image]

---

I would merely add a gradient as an additional fill via the **Appearance Panel**, along with the stroke. So the stroke encompasses the entire glyph and the fill is split by the gradient.

Simply make certain both gradient stops are at the exact same `Location` - 50%.

[image]

One *live text* object easily changed.

---

If you are concerned about the stroke adding to the size of the glyphs..

Set the type to have the same yellow fill:

[image]

Then use `Effect > Path > Offset Path` on the additional Gradient Fill to move it inward creating the *appearance* of a stroke without actually having a stroke present.

[image]

---

Drag the resulting text object to the **Graphic Styles Panel** and next time you need to apply it, it is merely one click away.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Stroke Panel (**Window → Stroke** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>)

And change the stroke alignment to "Align Stroke to Inside"

[image: Stroke Panel]

[image: Stroke Alignment Options]

---

If the text is still editable text, you will have to expand (outline) it first to do the above method. If that's the case and you don't want to expand it, use the simple method below.

---

You can also just leave a stroke on the half which is filled at the same thickness and alignment options as the outlined part.